# Combine datasets with partially different columns row-wise

Tags: dataset

I have a problem, which I assume to be trivial, but can't solve it:

I have two datasets,

`ds = Dataset@*
   Map[AssociationThread[{"ID", "Date", "A"} -> #] &]@{
{"C9", SQLDateTime[{2012, 12, 11, 0, 0, 0.}], 10},
{"C9", SQLDateTime[{2015, 2, 19, 19, 30, 0.}], 9},
{"C9", SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 22, 0, 0, 0.}], 12},
{"C10", SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 28, 9, 25, 0.}], 15},
{"C10", SQLDateTime[{2014, 3, 21, 20, 0, 0.}], 12}, 
{"C11", SQLDateTime[{2013, 8, 27, 6, 40, 0.}], 8}}`

and

`ds2 = Dataset@*
   Map[AssociationThread[{"ID", "Date", "B"} -> #] &]@{
{"C09", SQLDateTime[{2012, 12, 15, 1, 0, 0.}], 221},
{"C09", SQLDateTime[{2014, 1, 20, 0, 30, 0.}], 112},
{"C10", SQLDateTime[{2013, 1, 28, 0, 25, 0.}], 315},
{"C11", SQLDateTime[{2014, 3, 2, 6, 40, 0.}], 128}}`

which I want to combine to one, which looks like that in the end:

[image: resulting dataset]

So the rows are only written below each other and in the columns, where no value is available a placeholder is used.

The problem is, I don't know how to obtain, this result. Is it any specific use of `JoinAcross` or do I have to take the `Join` function or even something else?

Every hint is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SortBy["ID"]@JoinAcross[ds,ds2, {"ID", "Date"}, "Outer"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't use two arguments in the JoinAcross (but only the "ID") and got therefore puzzling results.

Comment: @Lea, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: I just stumbled about one question concerning your answer, which fits my purpose well. But I don't understand why it works, since in the JoinAcross docu it is mentioned: 

JoinAcross[{a1,a2,…},{b1,b2,…},{key1,key2,…}]

joins pairs of associations only when the values associated with all keys keyi are the same.    But the dates in the upper example are NOT the same. Can you help me to understand your solution?

Comment: @Lea, please see [JoinAcross  >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/JoinAcross.html) for details of  how the four-argument form (`JoinAcross[alist, blist, spec, "jspec"]`)  works: